# How do I create an ASP.NET webforms global value

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a webforms application with functions that frequently require a particular value, in this case the logged in user:

```
// Get user
string strUser = (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

What it the best way to populate this string only once and call it from everywhere in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can have a Session variable to hold it

```
Session["UserName"] = "myusername";
```

If its a session dependent variable like a logged in user name use `Session state`
else use `Application state`, Application state applies to all users and sessions

Answer (score 1):

you can use Application variable.

```
Application["username"] = "xyz";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare this variable at Global.asax file.

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a way to store a global value in web applications, they are state-less.
You can make use of a Session variable.

`Session["Login"] = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;`

The other thing you can do is create a `static` class with a `static` variable and assign the value on say `Page Load`.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso - You need to expand your comment what won't work?

Comment: because the session by default is InProc so it may not be initialized in another server of the server farm.
Using a static variable has the same issue as it will exist in the memory of each server

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso - where in the question did you see he was using a server farm?  Please re-read the question, had that been the case he / she would explicitly state that.

Comment: nowhere but we should always consider all the possible scenarios asthe OP may not be aware about that.
It is also a bad practice to store security-sensitive information in Session

Comment: Who said he is storing security sensitive information?  The post is an example of how to store a session variable.

Comment: but what's the point of adding something to the session that is already available in the Context?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx